# Storing a variable at a specific offset within a section

Tags: c, variables, gcc, memory, attributes

In GCC, I can ask for a variable to be located in a specific section:

```
int myVar __attribute__ ((section (".noinit")));
```

Is it possible to ask for this variable to be located specifically at offset 0x0000 in that section?

Comment: No, the positioning must be done by the linker file.  Otherwise you could have multiple files requesting the same address, or overlapping addresses.  You can make it ".noinit.first" and use a linker file to ensure that this is placed first.  By using input sections to order the output section.  Even if they are unique offsets, the linker would have to find all these and then fit the rest in the remaining space, but the linker typically doesn't know about structure sizes, etc and would not know if it can break items.  Offset 0 or max are the only legit choices, already accomplished by sections.